# How secure is a headless linux server with passwordless sudoers accounts

Tags: linux, security

The only means of accessing the server console is via ssh, using keys. Also via exploits of various services the server is running.

My administrative account (belongs to sudo group) has no password, but root does.

Is that considered unsecure?

Comment: So you can basically `su sudoers` from any account on the system and then run `sudo su` without password?

Comment: Don't know about former (says "no password entry for 'sudoers'"), but for the latter: yes.

Comment: Does `su ${your_admin_username}` work? If yes you basically have root access from every account on your system.

Comment: Yes, it does. Please remember that this is a headless server - not meant for anyone to even have access to shell except for my administrative account. Also, one would have to know name of my account.

Comment: Could the one with the downvote explain the downvote?

Comment: Secure vs. insecure is not a binary affair. There are always ways to improve a system, and you should be striving to do that. IMHO it is foolish to not have a password on your user account.

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](//$SITEURL/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](//$SITEURL/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Comment: @JennyD : agreed, but I googled on the subject and turned up nothing of use. I'm not really proficient at Linux and for a moment there it seemed a good idea as a key (as long as it's sufficiently protected) seems quite secure. I failed to realise that listing and impersonating users is easy in Linux (which sd40's answer explains well). This was a simple question which got a straight answer explaining why it's not a good idea. So, having an explained downvote would tell me what I did wrong asking the question. As it is, I still believe the question has its place here and the downvotes puzzle me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is that considered unsecure?"
Based on the information provided. I would have to say yes.
Here are some things I would be concerned about:

- What's to prevent someone from going to the server location, attaching a monitor, putting the server into single user mode, and resetting the root password?
- How are your ssh keys stored? Are they on an unencrypted laptop, flash drive, or other disk that could be easily stolen or misplaced?
- Is there a drac or ilo connection on the server with default or weak passwords that would grant someone console access?
- Is the console logged out? I've found many servers that when the console is accessed, the root user is still logged in from the last time it was accessed.
- Having a user without a password and with sudo access is a huge security hole no matter how it's exploited.
- Do you allow only key based authentication? If not, I would edit the ssh config to prevent password authentication attempts in case someone stumbles on your unprotected user account.
- Configuring a password for your user account takes two seconds, just do it.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question well. I thought using keys as a method of logging in would be secure, but forgot about all the other implications.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, you have an unprotected administrator user whose sole protection is that the username is uncommon (maybe). From this account, you can `sudo` without password so anyone who manages to run under your administrative user is essentially root.

`/etc/passwd` is readable by everyone which makes finding out the username fairly trivial so your administrator account basically has no security.

Like most systems, it is not designed to be accessed by anyone but its administrator(s). Unfortunately, like most systems, you have services exposed to the outside world and that makes your server vulnerable to a lot of potential attacks you (and most of the rest of the world) might not be aware of.

Granted, if you have no other users it lessens the risk but still, allowing to `su` to your administrator account which is in turn, capable of running root commands without protection is careless to say the least.
If you really can't stand the hassle of typing your `sudo` password, consider protecting your administrator user with a password, and removing the password prompt for your user in `/etc/sudoers`.

That still won't be great security, but at least your administrator account won't be as easily accessible.